# Save Google Map layer as in QGIS using Python script

Tags: qgis, python, raster, pyqgis

I am trying to save Google Maps by using save raster layer as via Python script:

```
urlWithParams = 'type=xyz&url=https://mt1.google.com/vt/lyrs%3Ds%26x%3D%7Bx%7D%26y%3D%7By%7D%26z%3D%7Bz%7D&zmax=19&zmin=0'    
rlayer = QgsRasterLayer(urlWithParams, 'Google Satellite', 'wms')    
renderer = rlayer.renderer()    
provider = rlayer.dataProvider()              
pipe = QgsRasterPipe()    
pipe.set(provider.clone())    
pipe.set(renderer.clone())    
extent = self.iface.mapCanvas().extent()    
crs = self.dockwidget.crs_select.crs()    
file_writer = QgsRasterFileWriter(self.dockwidget.input_path.text())    
file_writer.Mode(1)    
file_writer.writeRaster(pipe, provider.xSize(), provider.ySize(), extent, crs)
```

It works, but the result not as correctly as I do it by Export in QGIS.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

1. You shouldn't because you are probably breaking copyright
2. The CRS / SRID of these maps is quite limited. The projection you are saving to is likely different. You may need to learn more about these in light of your unstated end use
3. Google Maps is not really a raster...  have you considered just saving the image of the map canvas?